# Limit cache length of chrome notifications when Windows is locked

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome, notifications

Is there any sort of option in the Web API Notifications to allow a notification to not be displayed while the PC is locked?

I have setup a web application that displays Notifications when certain events happen. This is something I use at work to monitor different things so I leave it open nearly 24/7. Problem is that when the PC is locked, the notifications are saved until I unlock the PC. Then I  get flooded with all the notifications that were triggered while the PC was locked.

I cannot use an sort of idle page script to only show notifications if the page was used or interacted with in the last X number of minutes because I don't actually want to have to look at the page to still allow the notifications.

```
// set title and message body
var title = 'Test message';
var message 'This is a test message that should only show when logged into the PC';

// setup some options
var options = {
    // someOptionToDisableLockedNotificationsOnWindows?
    body: message,
    icon: 'assets/yukon_logo_small.png',
};

// create the notification using the above settings
var notification = new Notification( title, options );

// focus tab and close the notification on click
notification.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    window.focus();
    e.target.close();
}, false);
```

I have tried to randomly set some options, don't remember them all but they didn't do anything or broke my code.

I was not able to find anything in the API:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API

Comment: I've not personally tested it, but I assume the correct way is to call `close()` on old notifications when you create a new one.

Comment: @JosiahDaniels That could work but, javascript will not have anyway to tell if the notification has cleared due to a timeout or whether the PC is still locked and it has not been displayed yet. I do suspect there is a way to detect a locked pc this way though.

Comment: Actually, I forgot about the options.tag parameter. Would that be of use? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/tag

Comment: I can't think of a good way to use it. If o have an event happen 10 times in a minute,  i want this notifications seperate.